# How to read through a text file in python and count the number of times a certain character occurs in it?

Tags: python, css, text, count

New to programming,learning python.
This week are focusing on reading URL text files. Looking to read through a text file and count the amount of times the character "e" occurs.

```py
import urllib.request
content = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/old/moby10b.txt")
content.read()
counter = 0
for 'e' in content:
    counter +=1
print(counter)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a file on the internet, send a request to that address with the requests library. This returns you a response. 
response.text is the content of the web page

Try like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/old/moby10b.txt")

print(response.text.count("e"))
```

Output:

```
116960
```

Comment: I went for this .import urllib.request 
fname = input('enter file')
l = input('enter letter')

counter = 0
content = urllib.request.urlopen(fname).read().decode('utf-8')

for letter in content:
    if(letter==l):
     counter+=1

print(counter)